# Managing a variable number of worker threads with graceful exit

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, pthreads

I have a boss thread that spawns up to M worker threads. Over the lifetime of the program, workers may be added and removed. When the program-wide shutdown flag is signalled, I want to await the completion of these workers.

Currently, any of the threads can add/remove threads, but it's strictly not a requirement as long as any thread can *initiate* a spawn/removal.

What's stopping me from using a counting semaphore or `pthread_barrier_wait()` is that it expects a fixed number of threads.

I can't loop `pthread_join()` over all workers either because I'd risk leaking zombie threads that have exited and possibly since then been replaced.

The boss thread itself has no other purpose than spawning the threads initially and making sure that the process exits gracefully.

I've spent days on and off on this problem and cannot come up with something robust and simple; are there any fairly well-established ways to accomplish this with POSIX threads?

Comment: So you want a way of knowing all threads are officially killed, but have no way of knowing how many have actually been started ? It would seem addressing the second half of that question *first* would be paramount to a robust solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll take the opposite tac as some of the other answers since I have to do this now and again.

(1) Give every spawned thread access to a single pipe file descriptor either through the data passed through `pthread_create` or globally.  Only the boss thread reads the pipe.  Each thread announces its creation and termination to the boss via the pipe by passing its tid and boss adds or removes it from its list and `pthread_joins` it as appropriate. Boss can block on the pipe w/o having to do anything special.

(2) Do more or less the above with some other mechanism.  Global ctr and list with accompanying condition variable to wake up boss; a message queue, etc.

Comment: I like the first solution the most because it enables the boss thread to block on the pipe, effectively implementing `pthread_join_any()`. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

1) "Currently, any of the threads can add/remove threads"

and

2) "are there any fairly well-established ways to accomplish this with POSIX threads"

Yes. Don't do (1). Have the boss thread do it.

Or, you can protect the code which spawns threads with a critical section or mutex (I assume you are already doing this). They should check a flag to see if shutdown is in progress, and if it is, don't spawn any more threads.

You can also have a counter of "ideal number of threads" and "actual number of threads" and have threads suicide if they find "ideal > actual". (I.e. they should decrement actual, exit the critical section/mutex, then quit).

When you need to initiate shutdown, use the SAME mutex/section to set the flag. Once done, you know the number of threads cannot increase, so you can use the most recent value.

Indeed, to exit you can just have the boss thread set "ideal" to zero, exit the mutex, and repeatedly sleep 10ms and repeat until all threads have exited. Worst case is you wait an extra 10ms to quit. If that's too much cut it to 1ms.

These are just ideas. The central concept is that all thread creation/removal, and messages about thread creation/removal should be protected by a mutex to ensure that only one thread is adding/removing/querying status at a time. Once you have that in place, there is more than one way to do it...

Comment: These are solid suggestions. I'm not too fond of the exit strategy of sleeping and checking, but @Duck's answer addresses this. I'll accept his answer as it will most closely resemble the end result. Thank you.

Comment: @haste, you don't have to sleep and check, you can have a counting semaphore and wait on that instead. Whatever, do be aware that unless you join on the thread, the thread finalisation may still be running when the boss thread quits. You have to decide if this matters, and if it does then join the threads.

Answer (score 2):

Threads that want to initiate spawns/removals should ask the boss thread to actually do it for them. Then the boss thread doesn't have to worry about threads it doesn't know about, and you can use one of the simple methods you described in your question.